# How to download a file with HTML/Javascript with filename that starts with a dot [.]?

Tags: javascript, html, download, anchor

I know I can use `<a>` to download a file through HTML/Javascript but I don't know why it doesn't work when I want to give user, for example, a `.gitignore` file:

```js
const a = document.querySelector("a");
a.download = ".gitignore";

const blob = new Blob(["bin/"], {type: "text/plain"});
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

```html
<a target="_blank">Download .gitignore</a>
```

*The above code does not work in StackOverflow snippet*.

However, in a normal website in Chrome, the above code would download a file with `gitignore.txt` file instead. I tried Windows' syntax `.gitignore.` but the downloaded file name is `gitignore_.txt` instead. Is this a browser bug or a limitation of `download`? Is there any workaround?

Comment: For preventing the extension, use an uncommon mime such as: `type: "message/example"`. On the other hand, I don't think it is possible to save it as a dot file